# Is it possible to get public information of a user in facebook without requesting for its permission in the new open graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to get public information of a user without requesting for his/her permission? In facebook I know that we can get the basic informations of the user such as id, name, picture, gender, and his locale... without requesting for his permission?

Comment: Get it from what? What info do you have about the user?

Comment: lets say I have the id, or the link to the users profile (the name)